# Why is it not possible to burn a multisession DVD using brasero?

Tags: dvd, brasero

The multisession function works for CDs, but not for DVDs.

There is no option to add files after creating a Multisession DVD. Why is it not possible to create a multisession DVD with brasero?

Thank You.

Answer (score 8):

When burning it there is an option called **Leave the disc open to add other files later**

[image: Brasero Burner]

Click on Properties And the following Windows will appear:

[image: Brasero Properties]

Other users have reported that turning on DAO in **Edit > Modules > growisofs > Settings** also helped.

Lastly it also depends on the DVD Recorded you are using. Some models have been known to create this problem. Changing the unit helped.

Comment: thankyou for your answer! sadly, the option "leave the disc open to add other files later" or "properties" does not appear when i want to create a dvd. i don't want to burn iso's, just data-dvd's. with cd's , it works, but not with dvd's.