# How to make append-able CD?

Tags: burning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it not possible to burn a multisession DVD using brasero?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28044/why-is-it-not-possible-to-burn-a-multisession-dvd-using-brasero)

I want to make a append-able CD so that I can write data to it any time I want. I could do this using the native CD burner of Windows XP/7. But I know how to do this in windows. Can anyone help me?

Comment: i want to do it in ubuntu .. i know how to do it in windows

Comment: sorry for the mistake in the question!

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28044/why-is-it-not-possible-to-burn-a-multisession-dvd-using-brasero

Answer (score -1):

Answer on this link as said by user68186 :

> [Why is it not possible to burn a multisession DVD using brasero?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28044/why-is-it-not-possible-to-burn-a-multisession-dvd-using-brasero)

Comment: Parroting a comment as an answer is not an answer.